# Chrome Extension: Tab refresh causes page title to be lost (YouTube)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I change the tab title on a YouTube page and refresh the page, the title is overridden by the default video title. I used `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` to make sure that the page is fully loaded before changing the title, but when I refresh the page I can briefly see the new title before it is replaced with the original page's title. This also happens on Twitch, so maybe it's something to do with video sites?

## background.js

```
/* keeps the tab's title and color persistent tab refresh */
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{
    /* once content script has finished loading in the new tab, send a message with the tab's title to the content script; */

    if (changeInfo.status === "complete")
    {
        // tab's title was changed
        if (saveTitle[tabId] != null)
        {
            // tab's title sent to content script
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {title: saveTitle[tabId]}, function(response){});
        }
    }
})
```

## content script

```
/* sets the title of the tab */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.title)
    {
        document.title = request.title;
    }
})
```

Comment: Apparently the page changes the title in its script. Try removing `if (changeInfo.status === "complete")` so that the code runs on any update.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!